# How to reset/fix terminal sessoins (server), after I've killed its PID?

Tags: gnome-terminal, session, virtual-console, gnome-session, terminal-server

I was trying to kill responded window so I used `kill -9 PID`
and the PID was the ID of `/usr/libexec/gnome-terminal-server` by mistake. Now, every time I start terminal (even if it is a virtual terminal) it doesn't show anything as shown in the image below

[image]

and then I need to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> to begin using shell.

After clicking <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check the service alive or not

`systemctl --user status gnome-terminal-server status`

Then depends on the condition you can

`systemctl --user start gnome-terminal-server status`

or

`systemctl --user restart gnome-terminal-server status`